# MongoDB aggregate map by key and sum value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to aggregate the following by key and sum the value:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60dd5e0bd0ba24343dabc626"
    },
    "s": {
        "_71vnohpi4": {
            "q": 2
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "609ea0b0c85ca8e54adc610c"
    },
    "s": {
        "_71vnohpi4": {
            "q": 49
        },
        "_h2121audz": {
            "q": 20
       }
    }
}
```

Would like to sum the value like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "newid-doesntmatter"
    },
    "s": {
        "_71vnohpi4": {
            "q": 51
        },
        "_h2121audz": {
            "q": 20
       }
    }
}
```

Most of the examples available are for arrays, so `$unwind` doesn't work in my case. And since the keys are dynamic, I cannot specify the key name.

This is what I tried, but I can't group the keys.
[image: tried]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are aggregation operators like `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject`:

1. Convert object to array ( key-value pair)
2. Unwind to split into individual docs.
3. Again converting the value Object to array because it is again an object.
4. Unwind again
5. Group based on `id` and `key` (This will give the sum)
6. Group stage to combine inner most key/value.
7. Group stage to combine all documents.
8. Project using `$arrayToObject` to arrive at a single object.

   ```
   [{
   '$project': {
           's': {
               '$objectToArray': '$s'
           }
       }
   }, {
       '$unwind': '$s'
   }, {
      '$addFields': {
           's-v': {
               '$objectToArray': '$s.v'
           }
       }
   }, {
       '$unwind': '$s-v'
   }, {
       '$group': {
           '_id': {
               'id': '$s.k',
               'key': '$s-v.k'
           },
           'stats': {
               '$sum': '$s-v.v'
           }
       }
   }, {
       '$group': {
           '_id': '$_id.id',
           'sum': {
               '$mergeObjects': {
                   '$arrayToObject': [
                       [
                           [
                               '$_id.key', '$stats'
                           ]
                       ]
                   ]
               }
           }
       }
   }, {
       '$group': {
           '_id': '1',
           'obj': {
               '$push': {
                   'k': '$_id',
                   'v': '$sum'
                }
            }
        }
   }, {
       '$project': {
           'final': {
               '$arrayToObject': '$obj'
           }
       }
   }]
   ```

Comment: I ended up using these steps from your post, and they were enough. https://gist.github.com/fecogc/f9fb35a640afec9269a866adb0759482

Answer (score 1):

- `$objectToArray` convert `s` object to an array of objects in key-value format
- `$unwind` to deconstruct `s` array
- `$group` by key and count the value of `q`
- `$group` by null and construct the array of key-value pair object
- `$arrayToObject` convert above `s` array to object from key-value pair

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: { s: { $objectToArray: "$s" } } },
  { $unwind: "$s" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$s.k",
      count: { $sum: "$s.v.q" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      s: {
        $push: { k: "$_id", v: { q: "$count" } }
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { s: { $arrayToObject: "$s" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fGZgYY_fKCj)

Comment: This will not work if the inner must object's key isn't 'q'.

Comment: OP does not mention this in the question. he asked for "_71vnohpi4"  keys that are dynamic.